# Sharing session in two same web site hosted as different web application IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-4.0, stateserver

i have a senerio in what i want to share session between two web site having same code.
For example.

Website

------- WebSite1  (bind to abc.test.com)

------- WebSite2  (bind to xyz.test.com)

What i want is that when user go to  abc.test.com and signin thne when user hit xyz.test.com then site shows user as signin. but the problem is that i cant achieved that.

Am useing asp.net state server for saving session.Both site have same code and same confdig file. Any any body shade some light on how can i achieve that.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing session data between ASP.NET Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616046/passing-session-data-between-asp-net-applications)