# Passing data from one WebApplication to another via Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to pass data from WebApplication 1 to WebApplication 2.

WebApplication 1 contains data which I get and want to show that on webapplication 2.

My scenario is that I'm tracking visitors from my WebApplication 1 and showing their information on WebApplication 2.

Can anyone tell me the logic of my web service.  What I have so far is:

```
[WebMethod]
public string VisitorInfo() 
{
Values v = new Values();
return v.SendValue();
}
```

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just store the information in a common data store on the server (such as a database)?

Comment: Because i want to access data rapidly

Comment: Why would a database not be rapid?

Comment: Because my website can have 1000's of visitor at same time and if i start to send data to db n then retrieve it from there it will be :S:S :S

Comment: I don't quite follow what your code sample is trying to show. Can you explain what you've already got?

Comment: "1000's" really isn't that many...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a common area to store the data so multiple web applications can access it. Apart from the suggested comment above in regards to a database, you could look at some thing called http://memcached.org/. There are also shared sessions, there is a link for this one here: [Passing session data between ASP.NET Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616046/passing-session-data-between-asp-net-applications). You could if you wanted try to also store them in cookies and share them between you web applications, this way is not advised by some and I have not tried it, but can be done.