# Data from one website app to another webapp

Tags: c#

I have created a web site application to authenticate users (login) and based on user role, response.redirect the user to other websites. I used to pass role, email in the querystring but going forward i need to use another method to do so. I tired creating sessions, but the redirect doesn't seem to work.. Could someone guide or point me to a better approach?? I have only one submit button which authenticates against membership and a list of if conditions checking roles and reponse.redirecting user based on role..

Comment: Can you think of Server.Transfer?

Comment: i tired but i need the roles and email on the next website.. and it does not send the request.. needs a relative url.. also it is used i believe for same application.

Comment: Take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616046/passing-session-data-between-asp-net-applications

Comment: Pablo, I am exactly trying to do this.. singlesignon for multiple websites on the same server, but am unbale to transfer without querystring.. If I use query the redirect works fine else if I put the things in Session page not getting redirected..

Answer (score 1):

Found this is in a previous question, which might be helpful

Sharing session state between applications: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Sharing_session_state.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Andrew, many thanks for this but I need a less expensive and a quick  way; no sql and cookie route...

Comment: @user1645859 - What do you mean "less expensive" way.  You need to post what you have tried if you want help.

Comment: I have tried creating sessions but they dont seem to appear on the other website . Also, inexpensive as in using sessions, hidden fields without using sql server to access already persistent data.

Comment: Also, i have decided to migrate the application to MVC and have each of the other websites as controllers, so can pass data easily.