# asp.net session sharing between two application (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, visual-studio-2012

I have two web application (Asp.net - VB) one in VS 2005 and another is in VS 2012 - Now I have to share session between these two applications. Session state actually maintain in VS 2005 (Old project) and both application are hosted on same IIS (7.0). When I access page from VS 2012 project I have to use same session which was generated in VS 2005 project at same time.
Note: Both projects has same content, design, code etc.
Can anyone has idea or solutions on the same?

Comment: well it is good if you use session state as sqlsessionstate or stateserver.

Comment: Thanks Terror, project originally in VS 2005 so I do not want to change any or the things in old code(web.config, code, global.asax etc) my session state is inProc.

Answer (score 0):

there are similar threads as below

[Passing session data between ASP.NET Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616046/passing-session-data-between-asp-net-applications)
[Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)

AS  Terror.Blade said you may want to use sqlsession state

Cheers

Nirav

Comment: Ty but I do not want to change session state I want to use session that was generated in VS 2005 application. Session state is "inProc" in my application.

Comment: @JitendraSondarva By default, sessions are stored in memory and each application have theyr own memory. You can't share what's in the memory. You'll have to store the information in a common place (ex: database). Same thing will happen if you have load balancing or fail-overs.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use one application session variable in another application using IIS, Global.asax or any? Both application are running at same time in same IIS/Server.